# Sorting a Column that is not in the database MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to get a ascending/descending sort of a column that is not actually in the database.

Model:

```
   public int? Stewardship { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    public int? Culture { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Excellence")]
    public int? Delivery_Excellence { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    public int? Innovation { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    [Display(Name = "Greater Good")]
    public int? Greater_Good { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    [Display(Name = "Integrity and Openness")]
    public int? Integrity_And_Openness { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    public int? Balance { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 0 and 50")]
    [Display(Name = "Total Points")]
    public int? TotalPoints
    {
        get
        {
            return Stewardship + Culture + Delivery_Excellence + Innovation + Greater_Good + Integrity_And_Openness + Balance;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {

    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

        //ViewBag.TotalSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "total_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.StewardshipSortParm = sortOrder == "Stewardship" ? "stewardship_desc" : "Stewardship";
        ViewBag.CultureSortParm = sortOrder == "Culture" ? "culture_desc" : "Culture";
        ViewBag.DeliverySortParm = sortOrder == "Delivery Excellence" ? "delivery_excellence_desc" : "Delivery Excellence";
        ViewBag.InnovationSortParm = sortOrder == "Innovation" ? "innovation_desc" : "Innovation";
        ViewBag.GreaterSortParm = sortOrder == "Greater Good" ? "greater_good_desc" : "Greater Good";
        ViewBag.IntegritySortParm = sortOrder == "Integrity And Openness" ? "integrity_desc" : "Integrity And Openness";
        ViewBag.BalanceSortParm = sortOrder == "Balance" ? "balance_desc" : "Balance";
        //ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "Name" ? "name_desc" : "Name";
        var leaderboard = from s in db.Users
                       select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            //case "total_desc":
            //    leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.TotalPoints);
            //    break;

            case "name_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.UserDetails.firstName);
                break;

            case "Stewardship":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Stewardship);
                break;
            case "stewardship_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Stewardship);
                break;

            case "Culture":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Culture);
                break;
            case "culture_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Culture);
                break;

            case "Delivery Excellence":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Delivery_Excellence);
                break;
            case "delivery_excellence_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Delivery_Excellence);
                break;

            case "Innovation":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Innovation);
                break;
            case "innovation_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Innovation);
                break;

            case "Greater Good":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Greater_Good);
                break;
            case "greater_good_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Greater_Good);
                break;

            case "Integrity And Openness":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Integrity_And_Openness);
                break;
            case "integrity_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Integrity_And_Openness);
                break;

            case "Balance":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.Balance);
                break;
            case "balance_desc":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderByDescending(s => s.Balance);
                break;

            case "Name":
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.UserDetails.firstName);
                break;                

            default:
                leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(s => s.UserDetails.firstName);
                break;
        }
        return View(leaderboard.ToList());
    }
```

Index:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Stewardship", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.StewardshipSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Culture", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CultureSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delivery Excellence", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DeliverySortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Innovation", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.InnovationSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Greater Good", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.GreaterSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Integrity And Openness", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IntegritySortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Balance", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BalanceSortParm })
        </th>
        <th> 
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalPoints)
        </th>
    </tr>
```

I basically want to be able to sort each field with a link in the table header, which works fine with everything that is actually in the model/database, however I get a LINQ error because the TotalPoints column is not in the actual SQL database, the commented out part where it tries to sort the total points in the Controller is where I run into issues.